# How to use join query in Django?

Tags: django

I have 2 table which are Author and Book.

In author table, I have 'id' and 'name' field.

In book table, I have 'book_id' and 'author_id'(foreign key).

Here are my sql statement.It works in my database.

```
select "Author"."Name",count("BookId")
from "Author"
join "Book" on "Book"."AuthorId" = "Author"."Id"
group by "Author"."Name"
```

Author - model.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=50)
```

Book - model.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='BookId', primary_key=True)
    authorid = models.ForeignKey('authors.Author', models.DO_NOTHING,  db_column='AuthorId')
```

Now I want to get the `count of book.id` which is group by `AuthorId` that can get the `AuthorName` from Author table.

What should i do?

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: Furthermore grouping by `Author.name` looks a bit strange, since that means that two authors with the same name will be considered the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can *annotate* your objects, like:

```
Author.objects.annotate(book_count=Count('book'))
```

will give you, a `QuerySet` of `Author`s, where every `Author` (that originates from *this* `QuerySet`) will have an attribute `.book_count` with the number of books.

Your proposed query, is slightly different, since you group on the `name` of the `Author`, in that case the query is:

```
Author.objects.values('name').annotate(book_count=Count('book')).order_by('name')
```

this will result in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, and each dictionary will contain two keys: `name`, and `book_count`. Note however that with this approach, if two authors have the *same* name, then this will result in one dictionary with the book count "added up", which is probably *not* what you want.